# Constant Build issues with IIS not being able to find WebViewPage in System.Web.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

I keep running into the following exception

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'WebViewPage' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 27:      Line 28:      Line 29:     public class
>   _Page_Views_Content_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage { Line 30:          Line 31: #line hidden
>
> Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8df93262\ed60a52a\App_Web_index.cshtml.eba9863.jffbohqj.0.cs
>   Line: 29

So far doing a clean and a rebuild normally fixes the problem. The Dev Environment is using IIS, it seems like something is going wrong when IIS caches the binaries. From some trial and error it seems like the issue happens if a request is made to the site at the same time as the site is being built.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the problem? It seems to be a configuration issue as other developers with the same setup do not have the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the references in the project were falling back to a different version of MVC.